# How to show that any path $\gamma:[a, b]\rightarrow\mathbb C$ is rectifiable and that $L(\gamma)=\int_{a}^{b}|\gamma'(t)|dt$.

Tags: complex-analysis

How to show that any path $\gamma:[a, b]\rightarrow\mathbb C$ is rectifiable and that $L(\gamma)=\int_{a}^{b}|\gamma'(t)|dt$.

Definition:

Consider a partition $P,a=t_0\lt t_1\lt \ldots\lt t_n=b\; of\; [a, b]$ and define

$L(P)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|\gamma(t_{i+1}-\gamma(t_i)|$

The length of the curve , $L(\gamma)= sup\{L(P):P \;is\; a\; partition \;of\;[a,\;b]\}$

If $L(\gamma)\lt\infty$ then $\gamma$ is said to be rectifiable.

Comment: *Hint:* Any idea how to relate $\gamma(t_{i+1})-\gamma(t_i)$ with some $(t_{i+1}-t_i)\gamma'(\tau_i)$?

Comment: Mean value theorem

Answer (score 0):

Use triangle inequality $|\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\gamma(t_{i+1})-\gamma(t_i))|\leq\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|\gamma(t_{i+1})-\gamma(t_i)|=L(\gamma)$.

$|\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\gamma(t_{i+1})-\gamma(t_i))|=|\int_{t_0}^{t_n}\gamma'(t') dt'|, $

$|\gamma(t_{i+1})-\gamma(t_i)|=|\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}\gamma'(t') dt'| \leq \int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}|\gamma'(t')| dt'$.

You get the final inequality

$|\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\gamma(t_{i+1})-\gamma(t_i))|\leq L(\gamma) \leq \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}|\gamma'(t')| dt'$.

Use the mean value Theorem for the Limit and you are done.